# How to generate random numbers from cut-off log-normal distribution in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, statistics, distribution, random, probability-density

The radii `r` is drawn from a cut-off log-normal distribution, which has a following probability density function:

```
pdf=((sqrt(2).*exp(-0.5*((log(r/rch)).^2)))./((sqrt(pi.*(sigma_nd.^2))...
    .*r).*(erf((log(rmax/rch))./sqrt(2.*(sigma_nd.^2)))-erf((log(rmin/rch))./sqrt(2.*(sigma_nd.^2))))));
```

`rch`, `sigma_nd`, `rmax`, and `rmin` are all constants.

I found the explanation from the net, but it seems difficult to find its integral and then take inverse in Matlab.

Comment: Can you describe where the PDF comes from? i.e. what's the underlying distribution supposed to be.

Comment: @Nzbuu: Please the comment in your answer and the updated remark in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked, but my first instinct is that it looks like `log(r/rch)` is a [truncated normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution) with limits of `log(rmin/rch)` and `log(rmax/rch)`. So you can generate the appropriate truncated normal random variable, say `y`, then `r = rch * exp(y)`.

You can generate truncated normal random variables by generating the untruncated values and replacing those that are outside the limits. Alternatively, you can do it using the CDF, as described by @PengOne, which you can find on the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution).

I'm (still) not sure that your p.d.f. is completely correct, but what's most important here is the distribution.

Comment: The PDF is a cut-off log-normal distribution.

Comment: I thought so. Generate a truncated normal r.v. and take the exponential as described.

Answer (score 1):

If your PDF is continuous, then you can integrate to get a CDF, then find the inverse of the CDF and evaluate that at the random value.

If your PDF is not continuous, then you can get a discrete CDF using cumsum, and use that as your initial Y value in interp(), with the initial X value the same as the values the PDF was sampled at, and asking to interpolate at your array of rand() numbers.

Comment: I found the explanation on net, but I can't get its integral and then the inverse. Can you post the solution?

Comment: @S_H You could use [`cumtrapz`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/cumtrapz.html) to numerically integrate the PDF.

Answer (score 1):

it's not clear what's your variable, but i'm assuming it's `r`.

the simplest way to do this is, as Chris noted, first get the cdf (note that if r starts at 0, `pdf(1)` is Nan... change it to `0`):

```
cdf = cumtrapz(pdf);
cdf = cdf / cdf(end);
```

then spawn a uniform distribution (size_dist indicating the number of elements):

```
y = rand (size_dist,1);
```

followed by a method to place distribution along the cdf. Any technique will work, but here is the simplest (albeit inelegant)

```
x = zeros(size_dist,1);
for i = 1:size_dist
    x(i) = find( y(i)<= cdf,1);
end
```

and finally, returning to the original pdf. Use matlab numerical indexing to reverse course. Note:  use `r` and not `pdf`:

```
pdfHist = r(x);
hist (pdfHist,50)
```

Comment: Hi Rasman. Thanks for your answer. There's an error while I run this as follow: `??? Improper assignment with rectangular empty matrix.` on the line `x(i) = find(y(i)<=cdf,1)`

Comment: make sure cdf is defined (vs null). It will be null if any element of the pdf is Nan (e.g. @0, matlab will calculate it to be Nan; hence my note: change it to zero)

Comment: Is CDF well defined (simply plot it)? Is sum(pdf) a real number? How did you define `r`? cumtrapz(pdf) should result in a real number if the pdf is well defined (i.e. for all values of r >= 0).

Answer (score 0):

Probably an overkill for your distribution - but you can always write a [Metropolis sampler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolis_algorithm).

On the other hand - implementation is straight forward so you'd have your sampler very quick.